# Microsoft Office BeforeCloseHandler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I made a function in **vb.net for desktop application** that totally saved the documents before closed, I implemented it with the System.Threading.Timer.

I'm asking with favor on how you experienced it.

So, I made a timer to saved the documents before closed.

But, upon testing without the timer, just one call to the function or Handler, the documents are not saved before closed, because a dialog box appears asking to saved or not or cancel.

Is it really in need to have the timer?  because we know a timer could delay the system even a single milliseconds.

I setup the timer with 100 milliseconds.

But, I don't want to use the timer, I want to saved the documents before closed for just one call of the function.

Is it really using the timer is the solution? or it can be done with just one call setup?

If it can be done in one function call, then I think I'm missing a code.

Thanks for your opinion and experienced.

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.net?

Comment: @enderland , using VB.net, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the FormClosing event.  In the handler you can perform actions before the form closes you can even cancel the closing event.  Here's a an example:

```
Dim Saved As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If Not Saved Then
        Dim Result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your text?", "Save Text?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Select Case Result
            'Since pressing the No button will result in closing the form without
            'saving the text we don't need to handle it here
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes

                SaveText_Click()
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                e.Cancel = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Saved = False
End Sub
'SaveText is a button for the user to manually save the text on demand.
'Since we don't need the sender or the eventargs, we can handle the click event without them.
'this way we can call this like any sub without having to worry about providing the right parameters.
Private Sub SaveText_Click() Handles SaveText.Click
    'Add your procedure to save the text here
    Saved = True
End Sub
```

If you don't want the option to close without saving just omit the messagebox and the select block and just call SaveText() and include the code to save your data in there.

Comment: thats not really the answer, but thank you for helping. I was talking about > Microsoft Office BeforeCloseHandler

Comment: Since you don't want to save the document before your app closes, like your question seemed to indicate, then I assume you want to autosave the document when you close it.  This can easily be achieved in the [Document.Close method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af6z0wa2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which accepts a parameter to save or not save the document.